# Find the remainder Of an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, parity

Let, $S = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 + \ldots + 2016^{2016}$. What is the remainder when $S$ is divided by $2$?

Please give us an explanations for newbies like us.

Comment: An even number raised to an even number is even, while an odd number raised to an odd number is odd. So, you simply have to check whether there are an odd number of odd terms, which gives an odd sum, or whether there are an even number of odd terms, which gives an even sum. (The question is, in other words, asking whether the sum $S$ is even or odd.)

Comment: @KM101 : any integral power of an odd number is odd, not just an odd one. It doesn’t matter here.

Comment: Oh well, the statement was directed at the particular problem, but it would have been better to have mentioned *any integer power* for both cases of an even and odd base.

Comment: @KM101 i.e. $\bmod 2\!:\ n^k\equiv n\,$ for all $\,k>0\,$ so it reduces to $\,(1+2+3+\cdots +2016)\bmod 2,\,$ i.e. we can ignore the exponents.

Answer (score 3):

Every second term is even so has remainder 0 when divided by 2. Every other term is odd, so has remainder 1 when divided by 2. The result is then 
$$\frac{2016}{2}=1008=0 \mod{2}$$
I.e. the remainder is 0 when divided by 2.

Comment: Sir, can you please explain.We are Newbies.How to know that the sum is even or odd for any circumstance like this? and also what type of theory we should study for this kind of problems?

Comment: This is the study of Modular arithmetic - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic. When an even number is raised to any power, the result is even. When an odd number is raised to any power, the result is odd. So any even powers will have remainder 0, and the odd powers will have a remainder of 1.